# PyTorch Bucket Iterator not found

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch

`BucketIterator` is no longer available under `torchtext.data` in torchtext 0.9. Has it been removed or changed its location?

Answer (score 0):

With the release of torchtext 0.9, some backwards incompatible changes were introduced (see changelog [here](https://github.com/pytorch/text/releases/tag/v0.9.0-rc5)). Among them, you'll see that:

> [...] The legacy components are placed in `torchtext.legacy.data` folder as follows:
>
> - `torchtext.data.Pipeline` -> `torchtext.legacy.data.Pipeline`
> - `torchtext.data.Batch` -> `torchtext.legacy.data.Batch`
> - `torchtext.data.Example` -> `torchtext.legacy.data.Example`
> - `torchtext.data.Field` -> `torchtext.legacy.data.Field`
> - `torchtext.data.Iterator` -> `torchtext.legacy.data.Iterator`
> - `torchtext.data.Dataset` -> `torchtext.legacy.data.Dataset`
>
> This means, all features are still available, but within `torchtext.legacy` instead of torchtext.

Therefore, to access the `BucketIterator`, you'll now need to import it like this:

```py
from torchtext.legacy.data import BucketIterator
```